# fprintf for large matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to fprintf with a large matrix (1500x100 type of dimensions). I tried this:

```
for i=1:1500
      fprintf(filename,'%s %f \n', words_cell{i}, polS_matrix(i,:));
end
```

But I don't know how to write the `%s %f` part, because my matrix is a length 100 and it would be very troublesome to write 100 `%f`. Is there any way to do this easily? I have look in the matlab fprintf page, but I don't see anything that I can use.

Comment: Just construct the format string programmatically: `[repmat('%s ',n) ' %f \n']` for `n=100` or something.

Comment: Or, if the repeated part is `%f`, use `['%s ' repmat('%f ', 1, size(polS_matrix,2)) '\n']` to build the format string

Comment: @LuisMendo yeah I realized that after the edit time window. I figured OP should be able to defeat this obstacle:P

Answer (score 3):

You could use a nested `sprintf` for the matrix:

```
sprintf('%f ', polS_matrix(i,:))
```

This implicitly takes all the matrix elements even if there is only one `%f`, producing a string from all the numbers in row `i`.

You may also want to change the iteration index name to avoid shadowing the imaginary unit.

So, the code would be:

```
for k = 1:1500
    fprintf(filename,'%s %s \n', words_cell{k}, sprintf('%f ', polS_matrix(k,:)));
end
```

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
for i=1:1500
      fprintf(filename,strcat('%s ', repmat('%f ',1,100), ' \n'), words_cell{i}, polS_matrix(i,:));
end
```

or, for performance:

```
formatSpecifiersString = strcat('%s ', repmat('%f ',1,100), ' \n');
for i=1:1500
      fprintf(filename, formatSpecifiersString, words_cell{i}, polS_matrix(i,:));
end
```

[ edit: added space in repmat('%s'..) --> repmat('%f '..) ]

Comment: Thanks, this is just perfect. But I realised that now it disappears the white space between the data. I am doing something wrong?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I fixed it. Forgot the space near the '%f' inside the repmat call. :)

Comment: Ok, I have seen that `strcat` makes the whitespace disappear, so then you would have to enter between each format the 32 ASCII, the whitespace. Something like this `fprintf(filename,strcat('%s',32, repmat('%2.2f',1,3), ' \n'), words_cell{i}, polS_matrix(i,:));` but with each `%f`. I tried also the method of @LuisMendo and doesn't have this issue.

Comment: @LuisMendo's method is also probably more efficient, definitely in cases with variable-length rows. Not sure about fixed-length rows - my solution my be a bit faster in that case. Doesn't really matter, though, what matters is readability for future users of the codebase.

Also, the issue was just a missing space near '%2.2f' --> '%2.2f ', that would add the space you required. :)

Answer (score 1):

I would rely on the vetorized nature of `fprintf` and use three separate calls to the file stream:

```
for i=1:size(polS_matrix,1)
    fprintf(filename ,  '%s' , words_cell{i});
    fprintf(filename , ' %f' , polS_matrix(i,:));
    fprintf(filename , '\n');
end
```